# Display link as hyperlink enabled output from mysql in php page but I am getting error

Tags: php, mysql, html-table, href

If I execute this I am getting output properly:

```
echo "<a href="'.$elink.'">'.$elink.'</a>";
```

but when I want to display my output in a table column format I am not able to insert:

```
echo "<td width='200'>" <a href="'.$elink.'">'.$elink.'</a>   "</td>";
or
echo "<td width='200'>" "<a href="'.$elink.'">'.$elink.'</a>"   "</td>";
or
echo "<td width='200'>" '<a href="'.$elink.'">'.$elink.'</a>   "</td>";
```

Comment: try this `echo "<a href='".$elink."'>".$elink."</a>";`

Comment: You should use `style="width:200px;"` instead of the deprecated `width='200'`

Answer (score 1):

Please correct the syntax errors.

```
echo '<td width="200">' .  '<a href="'.$elink.'">'.$elink.'</a></td>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have mismatched quotes.  But I would use sprintf.

```
echo sprintf("<td width='200'><a href='%1$s'>%1$s</a></td>", $elink);
```

Comment: `echo sprintf()` is an "antipattern". There is absolutely no reason that anyone should ever write `echo sprintf()` in any code for any reason -- it should be `printf()` without `echo` every time.

Answer (score 1):

First off you quotes are messed up. They should look like this:

```
echo "<td width='200'> <a href='".$elink."'>".$elink."</a></td>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Correct your string format

```
echo '<td width="200"><a href="'. $elink. '">' . $elink . '</a></td>';
```

I suggest you to use the attribute style (`style="width:200px;"`) instead the width attribute.
Remember to Url Encode the parameters contained in the *href* attribute.